# JS import/export module - 404 file not found

Tags: javascript, html

I tryed create a app which convert domain to IP. I'm new so please be understanding.
*file check-ip.js*

```
import check from './function';

const getDNS = document.querySelector('.enter_dns');
const { value } = getDNS;
const showIP = document.querySelector('.show_ip');
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  check(value, showIP);
});
```

*file function.js*

```
export default function check() {
  const { lookup } = require('dns');

  lookup(value, (error, address) => {
    if (error === null) {
      showIP.innerText = address;
    } else {
      showIP.innerText = `Ups, ${error}`;
    }
  });
}
```

*html*

```
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
      <h2 class="header">Enter www address to check IP:</h2>
      <span class="interaction">
        <input type="text" class="enter_dns" placeholder="domain name...">
        <button class="btn">CHECK</button>
      </span>
      <p class="show_ip"></p>
    </div>

    <script type="module" src="./js/function.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="./js/check-ip.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

When I'm using CommonJS I have a problem: required is not defined, so I try by export/import module. I see this error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygh7K.png)

Comment: `'./function.js'`, not `'./function'`. Isn’t the error message clear about this? If you import `function.js` from `check-ip.js`, then remove the superfluous `<script type="module" src="./js/function.js"></script>`. Also, try using `.mjs` instead of `.js` and double-check that the `package.json` has the correct `type` configured.

Comment: When I rename path from ```./function``` to ```./function.js``` i have error reqiured is not defined. Where I can check that my package.json is correct configured ?